# Display more than one attribute in symbology in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro

I want to color code temperature and represent precipitation by dot density in the same map.

How can I do this in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Something like this would work by using Multiple Attributes, unsure if this is still available in ArcGIS Pro: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010616

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if I'm understanding your questions correctly: so you want to display values of MULTIPLE fields in the symbology?

If so, what I'd do is to use Unique Values as the Primary symbology method.
[image: Steps]
And just add the field that you want to include, which will be `temp` and `p` in your case.

Comment: This would only allow display in colors for both fields. I wanted one field to be displayed in dot density and another in color.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Dot Density method for your symbology, you can create custom expressions based on your attributes:

[image: Dot Density Symbology Dialogue]

This seems to be easier if you break up your continuous variables into categorical brackets, since you can set a unique color and dot density for each bracket. If this is difficult to do in the custom dialogue box (the green *X*), try creating a new field with an ID for each temperature-precipitation combination bracket and using that for your custom expression:

[image: Expression builder dialogue]

(Note: I made this with a shapefile I had on hand. Yours may look different.)
Unfortunately, if you have a lot of categories, you'll have to set them one by one: `$feature.Id == 1`, `$feature.Id == 2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add the layer a second time; turn all the symbology to colorless. Label both layers, one per attribute.